# Mongo array querying with an index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Can someone explain this behavior?

```
db.inventory.insertMany( [
   { item: "journal", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: null }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 15 } ] },
   { item: "notebook", instock: [ { warehouse: "C", qty: 5 } ] },
   { item: "paper", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 60 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 } ] },
   { item: "planner", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 40 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 5 } ] },
   { item: "postcard", instock: [ { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 35 } ] }
]);
```

Copied from https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

but the first item, `instock.0.qty` is replaced with `null`.

Consequently, this query produces strange results:

```
> db.inventory.find({"instock.0.qty": null})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6194329212c7421dbaaeac81"), "item" : "journal", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : null }, { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 15 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6194329212c7421dbaaeac82"), "item" : "notebook", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 5 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6194329212c7421dbaaeac83"), "item" : "paper", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 60 }, { "warehouse" : "B", "qty" : 15 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6194329212c7421dbaaeac84"), "item" : "planner", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 40 }, { "warehouse" : "B", "qty" : 5 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6194329212c7421dbaaeac85"), "item" : "postcard", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "B", "qty" : 15 }, { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 35 } ] }
```

EDIT:
I'm expecting only one result, yet they all come back.

Comment: Actually, you inserts `null` https://ibb.co/bBBDVjK

Comment: Yea, that was intentional. I'm only expecting one result in the query, yet all the documents are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar issue was reported in this Jira ticket: [Incorrect filter result when using a null match inside an indexed array field](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-55739).

The proposed suggestion was using [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) to check the value which is null.

```
db.collection.find({
  "instock.0.qty": {
    $type: "null"
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cLUto_aLMu0)